# Adding values to float in Java slows down at 512

Tags: java, floating-point, floating-accuracy

This line is executing in a loop:

```
shape.setPosX(shape.getPosX() + (.005f * (float) getDelta()));
```

*getDelta* is the milliseconds passed since the last loop as a double, usually averaging at ~0.001.

*setPosX* accepts and stores the float value.

*getPosX*, as you can guess, returns the float value

When the shape is drawn I see it steadily move across the screen but once X hits 512 it slows down by what seems like a factor of 10. I can reproduce it 100% of the time so it's a pretty big blocker.

What could be going on here?

Comment: What is the sequence of values?

Comment: CAUTION: Earth is a sphere (you can not add a X(lon) to a shape)
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48085877/leaflet-create-a-marker-with-latlon-distance-meter-angle-degree

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Below 512: 110.05837 + (.005f * 0.002474) 
Above 512: 512.2892 + ( .005f * 0.002475)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `float` you are using have not enough number of digits of precision to represent the number. You can check this by telling Java to determine if (`512f + 0.005f * 0.001f == 512f`) [(it is `true`.)](https://ideone.com/giOAjB)

In 32-bit floating point numbers, the least significant bit for the mantissa for values between 256 and 512 is around `.00003` which happens to be enough for your getDelta() to push over (which suggests that your assumption that the value averages at `0.001f` might be wrong). The least significant bit for the mantissa for values between 512 and 1024 doubles to `.00006` (since the exponent part is one more). Your `getDelta` returns something that rounds up around once every 5 time or so, thus the speed is slowed ten-fold.

You can play around with `float`s [here](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html).

The solution to this is to make your number a `double`.

Fun trivia: floating point arithmetics is causes Minecraft to behave funny in high coordinates. The effects are described in [this page](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Far_Lands), although the actual bug might just be integer overflow.

Comment: Nicely explained. I had no idea this was going on behind the scenes... I converted the Shape class to have doubles and new methods (e.g. getPosXF) for casting before adding to the matrices and everything works beautifully, Thanks!

Comment: By the way, if you get up to `274877906944` with `double`, you will hit the same problem. But since this is a coordinate point, you will most likely never have to worry about this!

Comment: And at that point I guess your only option (if long double isn't available) is to scale all the values in the program down so the limit is reached slower?

Comment: If you are showing a viewport of offset of that magnitude, probably you should use a local coordinate system (say relative to the 0,0 of the window) and store the offset somewhere else. If you window is literally in the order of 10^24 pixels, then surely there will be 1024(or more?)-bit floats.